# Pulling data from google spanner to BigQuery for Data Data analysis?

Tags: google-bigquery

What's the best way to pull the data from cloud spanner to BigQuery for Data Analysis?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Google provided dataflow template for pulling data from Spanner to GCS, then run a load job to load it into Bigquery.

[Export Spanner database](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/export)

[Cloud Spanner to GCS AVRO](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates#cloud_spanner_to_gcs_avro)

Comment: Thanks Pavan Kumar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337117/gcp-what-is-the-best-option-to-setup-a-periodic-data-pipeline-from-spanner-to-b/56396713#56396713

Answer (score 0):

check this [Link1](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/replicating-cloud-spanner-bigquery-scale). you dont need any external service to migrate data. you can directly read all spanner data through Bigquery and load it.