# GCP: What is the best option to setup a periodic Data pipeline from Spanner to Big Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-spanner

**Task**: We have to setup a periodic sync of records from Spanner to Big Query. Our Spanner database has a relational table hierarchy.

**Option Considered** I was thinking of using Dataflow templates to setup this data pipeline.

- *Option1*: Setup a job with Dataflow template 'Cloud Spanner to Cloud Storage Text' and then another with Dataflow template 'Cloud Storage
  Text to BigQuery'. *Con*: The first template works only on a single table and we have many tables to export.
- *Option2*: Use 'Cloud Spanner to Cloud Storage Avro' template which exports the entire database. *Con*: I only need to export selected tables within a database and I don't see a template to import Avro into Big Query.

**Questions**: Please suggest what is the best option for setting up this pipeline

Comment: Could you not read directly from Spanner and write to BQ in one pipeline? https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dataflow-connector

Comment: Yes I thought about this option but In am a bit concerned on performance of that option. We have around 120M records in spanner (excluding data in all child tables that will be added in it). Our initial thought was to refresh full data set but alternate is to consider only delta i.e. what is changed today. I have raised a feature request to google team for providing a template from spanner to BQ directly.

Comment: We read billions of rows in our Dataflow pipelines without any problems. It will autoscale for you. Why do you need Google to create a template? You could just code it up yourself..

Comment: Yes we can code anything and that is our last option. But my intention of asking was if there is a better way of doing it since its a common use case for anyone using Spanner. Anyways thanks I got the answer.

Comment: @Ayush - what's your answer?

Comment: Dataflow is your safest bet, especially given the amount of data you are talking about.

Comment: I've added an example Dataflow pipeline that reads from Spanner and writes to BigQuery in one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single Dataflow pipeline to do it in one shot/pass. Here's an example I wrote using the Java SDK to help get you started. It reads from Spanner, transforms it to a BigQuery `TableRow` using a `ParDo`, and then writes to BigQuery at the end. Under the hood it's using GCS, but that's all abstracted away from you as a user.

[image]

```
package org.polleyg;

import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableFieldSchema;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableSchema;
import com.google.cloud.spanner.Struct;
import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.SpannerIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED;
import static org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE;

/**
 * Do some randomness
 */
public class TemplatePipeline {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PipelineOptionsFactory.register(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
        DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
        PCollection<Struct> records = pipeline.apply("read_from_spanner",
                SpannerIO.read()
                        .withInstanceId("spanner-to-dataflow-to-bq")
                        .withDatabaseId("the-dude")
                        .withQuery("SELECT * FROM Singers"));
        records.apply("convert-2-bq-row", ParDo.of(new DoFn<Struct, TableRow>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                row.set("id", c.element().getLong("SingerId"));
                row.set("first", c.element().getString("FirstName"));
                row.set("last", c.element().getString("LastName"));
                c.output(row);
            }
        })).apply("write-to-bq", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                .to(String.format("%s:spanner_to_bigquery.singers", options.getProject()))
                .withCreateDisposition(CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                .withWriteDisposition(WRITE_TRUNCATE)
                .withSchema(getTableSchema()));
        pipeline.run();
    }

    private static TableSchema getTableSchema() {
        List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("id").setType("INTEGER"));
        fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("first").setType("STRING"));
        fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("last").setType("STRING"));
        return new TableSchema().setFields(fields);
    }
}
```

Output logs:

```
00:10:54,011 0    [direct-runner-worker] INFO  org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchLoads - Writing BigQuery temporary files to gs://spanner-dataflow-bq/tmp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_templatepipelinegrahampolley0531141053eff9d0d4_3dd2ba3a1c0347cf860241ddcd310a12/ before loading them.
00:10:59,332 5321 [direct-runner-worker] INFO  org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableRowWriter - Opening TableRowWriter to gs://spanner-dataflow-bq/tmp/BigQueryWriteTemp/beam_load_templatepipelinegrahampolley0531141053eff9d0d4_3dd2ba3a1c0347cf860241ddcd310a12/c374d44a-a7db-407e-aaa4-fe6aa5f6a9ef.
00:11:01,178 7167 [direct-runner-worker] INFO  org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables - Loading 1 files into {datasetId=spanner_to_bigquery, projectId=grey-sort-challenge, tableId=singers} using job {jobId=beam_load_templatepipelinegrahampolley0531141053eff9d0d4_3dd2ba3a1c0347cf860241ddcd310a12_b4b4722df4326c6f5a93d7824981dc73_00001_00000-0, location=australia-southeast1, projectId=grey-sort-challenge}, attempt 0
00:11:02,495 8484 [direct-runner-worker] INFO  org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl - Started BigQuery job: {jobId=beam_load_templatepipelinegrahampolley0531141053eff9d0d4_3dd2ba3a1c0347cf860241ddcd310a12_b4b4722df4326c6f5a93d7824981dc73_00001_00000-0, location=australia-southeast1, projectId=grey-sort-challenge}.
bq show -j --format=prettyjson --project_id=grey-sort-challenge beam_load_templatepipelinegrahampolley0531141053eff9d0d4_3dd2ba3a1c0347cf860241ddcd310a12_b4b4722df4326c6f5a93d7824981dc73_00001_00000-0
00:11:02,495 8484 [direct-runner-worker] INFO  org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables - Load job {jobId=beam_load_templatepipelinegrahampolley0531141053eff9d0d4_3dd2ba3a1c0347cf860241ddcd310a12_b4b4722df4326c6f5a93d7824981dc73_00001_00000-0, location=australia-southeast1, projectId=grey-sort-challenge} started
00:11:03,183 9172 [direct-runner-worker] INFO  org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl - Still waiting for BigQuery job beam_load_templatepipelinegrahampolley0531141053eff9d0d4_3dd2ba3a1c0347cf860241ddcd310a12_b4b4722df4326c6f5a93d7824981dc73_00001_00000-0, currently in status {"state":"RUNNING"}
bq show -j --format=prettyjson --project_id=grey-sort-challenge beam_load_templatepipelinegrahampolley0531141053eff9d0d4_3dd2ba3a1c0347cf860241ddcd310a12_b4b4722df4326c6f5a93d7824981dc73_00001_00000-0
00:11:05,043 11032 [direct-runner-worker] INFO  org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl - BigQuery job {jobId=beam_load_templatepipelinegrahampolley0531141053eff9d0d4_3dd2ba3a1c0347cf860241ddcd310a12_b4b4722df4326c6f5a93d7824981dc73_00001_00000-0, location=australia-southeast1, projectId=grey-sort-challenge} completed in state DONE
00:11:05,044 11033 [direct-runner-worker] INFO  org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables - Load job {jobId=beam_load_templatepipelinegrahampolley0531141053eff9d0d4_3dd2ba3a1c0347cf860241ddcd310a12_b4b4722df4326c6f5a93d7824981dc73_00001_00000-0, location=australia-southeast1, projectId=grey-sort-challenge} succeeded. Statistics: {"completionRatio":1.0,"creationTime":"1559311861461","endTime":"1559311863323","load":{"badRecords":"0","inputFileBytes":"81","inputFiles":"1","outputBytes":"45","outputRows":"2"},"startTime":"1559311862043","totalSlotMs":"218","reservationUsage":[{"name":"default-pipeline","slotMs":"218"}]}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you able to pull the 15million record with SpannerIO.read()?

Comment: Yes, this solution will scale.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no off-the-shelf parameterized direct export from Cloud Spanner to BigQuery.

To meet your requirements, a custom dataflow job ([spanner dataflow connector](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dataflow-connector), [dataflow templates](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates)) scheduled periodically ([1](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#is_there_a_built-in_scheduling_mechanism_to_execute_pipelines_at_given_time_or_interval), [2](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/)) would be the best bet.  Incremental exports would require implementing change tracking in you database which can be done with [commit timestamps](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/commit-timestamp).

For a no-code solution, you would have to relax your requirements and bulk export all tables periodically to Cloud Storage and bulk import them periodically into BigQuery. You could use a combination of a [periodic trigger](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating#) of an [export from Cloud Spanner to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#cloudspannertogcsavro) and schedule a periodic [import from Cloud Storage to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-storage-transfer).